# Unusual most general unifier example

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, unification

we're trying to unify the following:

#### P(x,f(y)) and P(z,z)

(where P is a binary predicate, f is a unary function and x,y,z are variables)

Following the algorithm, I first include the following substitution: x / z.

Again, following the algorithm, the second one should be: z / f(y).

So our unified formula should be:

P(f(y),f(y))

..... which seems kind of weird to me, since we substitute something that has already been substituted.

Is the result right or did I make a mistake somewhere? Can someone check, please? I can't get over the skepticism here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RobArthan Hey, sorry for the unclarity. I messed it up, the input for the algorithm should've been P(x,f(y)) and P(z,z), not the clauses. Edited it, now it should be fine.

Comment: The question is fine now. Your result is right.  The composition of substitutions is what is needed to keep the overall substitution you are trying to find *idempotent*. If you haven't heard that term before, it might help if you said a bit more about the unification algorithm you are using.